# How to insert space after comma in nested array?

Tags: javascript

```
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    var current = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        current[arr1[i][1]] = arr1[i][0];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++){
        if (current.hasOwnProperty(arr2[i][1])) {
            current[arr2[i][1]] = current[arr2[i][1]] + arr2[i][0];
        } else {
            current[arr2[i][1]] = arr2[i][0];
        }
    }
    return Object.keys(current).map(function(val) {
        return [current[val],val];
    });
}

updateInventory([[21, "Bowling Ball"], [2, "Dirty Sock"], [1, "Hair Pin"], [5, "Microphone"]], [[2, "Hair Pin"], [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"], [67, "Bowling Ball"], [7, "Toothpaste"]]);
```

Ok so the result is for example `[[21, "Bowling Ball"],[2, "Dirty Sock"],[1, "Hair Pin"],[5, "Microphone"]]` and it needs to be like in the function call (with spaces after commas). In other words I can't figure out how to fix this line:

```
return Object.keys(current).map(function(val) {
    return [current[val],val];
});
```

Comment: Why does it need the spaces?

Comment: How about formatting the string yourself? something like 
 
`"[" + current[val] + ", "\"" + val + "\"]";`

Comment: In the output you get the array with arrays in it and those arrays are separated by commas but should be separated with comma + space.

Comment: The result is not a string. There are no commas in the first place. That's merely how the default console debug representation of an array looks like (I assume)… Why do you care how that's formatted?!

Comment: @deceze because the freecodecamp doesn't want to accept it as solution (although it is correct) just because the spaces are missing. I asked around on their chat but nobody seems to know how to do it.

Comment: FCC asks that the array be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: @Gavin I am an idiot. Yes, the array needs to be sorted in alphabetical order and I assumed it needs to stay in the order it was inputed.

Comment: @Filip Even if that was the case… **objects are unordered** and the order won't be kept (or wouldn't be guaranteed to be kept) anyway.

Comment: @deceze In my case with `Object.keys(current).map` the order was preserved.

Comment: **By chance only.** It will be more or less random in what order `Object.keys()` returns the keys. (Implementation details may be responsible for more or less preserving the order, but again, only by chance.)

Comment: @deceze `var current = {};
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
 current[i] = 1;
}


var final = Object.keys(current).map(function(val) {
        return [val];
    });
console.log(final);`
How come this returns all 100 numbers in the correct order they were inserted as objects?

Comment: Again: implementation specific details. It's not going out of its way and is actively randomizing it after all. This is not specified or guaranteed behavior though.

Comment: Change 100 to 1 million and it will still sort them in the array by the correct order they were created. It's not random, if it were random then the chances of it happening would be astronomical. Ether it's not random or I am the luckiest person in the history of humans.

Comment: It's not like I'm making this up, these are documented facts: *"The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop…"*, *"The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in ___arbitrary order___."* - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys - I'm not going to repeat the point about implementation specific details if you didn't get it by now.

Answer (score 1):

next time better point to the challenge https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/inventory-update

PS: don't you dare telling me it doesn't print what you expect, because the challenge says it passes, check it yourself

```js
function updateInventory(arr1, arr2) {
    var inv = {};
    for (var i in arr1) {
        inv[arr1[i][1]] = inv[arr1[i][1]] || 0;
        inv[arr1[i][1]] += arr1[i][0];
    }
    for (var i in arr2) {
        inv[arr2[i][1]] = inv[arr2[i][1]] || 0;
        inv[arr2[i][1]] += arr2[i][0];
    }
    var arr3 = [];
    Object.keys(inv).sort().forEach(function(key) {
        arr3.push([inv[key], key]);
    });
    console.log(arr3);
    return arr3;
}

// Example inventory lists
var curInv = [
    [21, "Bowling Ball"],
    [2, "Dirty Sock"],
    [1, "Hair Pin"],
    [5, "Microphone"]
];

var newInv = [
    [2, "Hair Pin"],
    [3, "Half-Eaten Apple"],
    [67, "Bowling Ball"],
    [7, "Toothpaste"]
];

updateInventory(curInv, newInv);
```

Comment: Well your code has the exact same outputs as my code but your code passes while my code doesn't. It's bugged then.

Comment: you're missing a detail `.sort()`

Comment: @Filip How are you coming to the conclusion that both outputs are identical? They're clearly not.

Comment: @deceze he means for the first set of sample data, which happens to come already sorted

Comment: @arhak Well, his code is in fact not predictable, since he's implicitly relying on object key order (or is just ignoring the order altogether, who knows?).